# Method of reading next line after a condition is satisfied in python

Tags: python

I have an input .txt file in the format:

```
1. ##Header1
2. 100    200
3. 
4. ##Header2
5. ABCDEFG
```

I want to read the line `##Header1`, and then go to the next line and save it as a variable.

I have seen suggestions to use `next()` but as the line in the input file is a string (not an iterator), I get an error. Here is my code:

```
    with open(file_name, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            if "##Header1" in line:
                contents_of_next_line = next(line)
```

Comment: You have no function definition in your post.  It's not clear what the function is supposed to do overall.

Answer (score 0):

Try `next(fin)` instead of `next(line)`. `fin` is the iterator, calling `next` on it will yield you the next line.